# Removing Memcache and Memcached from a Centos server

Tags: web-hosting, server, administration, memcached

A while back I started looking into caching, (I think) I mistakenly installed both Memcache and Memcached.

If I cd / then I have both:

```
memcache/memcache-3.0.6
memcached/memcached-1.4.10
```

[image: Screenshot]

How should I go about removing these completely from the server?

I'm using Centos if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

How did you install it?  If you installed it using `yum` then you should be able to remove it the same way.

First list the memcache packages installed:

`yum list memcache*`

Then remove the packages (probably two of them):

`yum remove [package name from list]`